# In a Unity 2D Text component, is the property fontSize in units?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a 5x5 grid based game as a learning project and am having difficulty getting text to display and scale properly when nested in a prefab with a background image in it.

is fontSize in Units? If not, what is fontSize relative to? The text is either gigantic, or small, but blurred to the point of a smudge.

I feel like the documentation on this subject is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Could you give more details about your prefab? (hierarchy, components, etc...) (and a picture vould be great! :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forum thread is a little dated, but it might be helpful for you to see how they based font size on screen size:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/changing-text-size-relative-to-screen.102876/

Agreed, the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Font.html) could be clearer on this:

"Adjusting the font size effectively changes how many pixels are used for each glyph in this generated texture. Text Mesh assets are 3d geometry textured with these auto-generated font textures. You will want to vary the size of the font to make these assets look crisp"